# Which Christian sects do not beleive in original sin?

Tags: original-sin

Which Christian sects do not beleive in original sin?
(Just like many sects do not beleive in Trinity.)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).
About your question, since there are tens of thousands of Christian sects, it simply wouldn't be possible to list all of the ones that do not believe in original sin.
However, though your question will likely be closed, I do hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: How do you define original sin?  Wikipedia says: "This condition has been characterized in many ways, ranging from something as insignificant as a slight deficiency, or a tendency toward sin yet without collective guilt, referred to as a 'sin nature,' to something as drastic as total depravity or automatic guilt of all humans through collective guilt."